# Integer field not autoincrementing in SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have a Flask-SQLAlchemy model with an `Integer` field that I'd like to autoincrement. It's not a primary key; it's a surrogate ID. The model looks like:

```
class StreetSegment(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, autoincrement=True)
    seg_id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
```

When I create the table in my Postgres database, the `id` field is created as a plain integer. If I insert rows without specifying a value for `id`, it doesn't get populated. Is there some way I can force SQLAlchemy to use `SERIAL` even if it isn't the primary key?

Answer (score 7):

Use [`Sequence`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/defaults.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Sequence) instead of `autoincrement`:

```
id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.Sequence("seq_street_segment_id"))
```

Comment: I dropped that into my model but when I migrate (with `flask_migrate`) no changes are detected.

Comment: @Jura Alembic is not a fully automatic solution. You need to write the migration yourself if it's not detected automatically.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. Even after I delete the DB and start again, it just enters a blank value for `id`.

Comment: @ChickenFeet Are you sure you're creating the sequence when you're creating the db? Try to print out the queries SQLAlchemy issues when you do `create_all()`.

Comment: No I am not sure. I am using an automatic db_create & db_migrate from the blog: https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-iv-database. In any case I have decided to move away from auto-increment and I'll just manually set it up each time I create a new record. Thanks for your answer anyway, I have seen some answers similar to your so I am sure you're recommended the right solution :)

Answer (score 1):

SQLAlchemy [does not](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Column.params.autoincrement) support `auto_increment` for non-primary-key columns.

If your database supports it, you can setup the same behavior using sequences. PostgreSQL supports this. Sequences actually are not bound to a very specific column. Instead, they exist on the database level and can be reused. Sequences are the exact construct, SQLAlchemy uses for auto incrementing primary-key columns.

To use a sequence as described in the accepted answer, it must exist. Following, I have an example of an alembic migration with SQLAlchemy to achieve that.

You can associate a sequence with a column in the [column constructor](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/metadata.html#sqlalchemy.schema.Column). The [DDL Expression Constructs API](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/core/ddl.html#ddl-expression-constructs-api) helps you creating and dropping the sequence.

An example:

```py
from alembic import op
import sqlalchemy as sa

measurement_id_seq = sa.Sequence('Measurement_MeasurementId_seq') # represents the sequence


def upgrade():
  op.execute(sa.schema.CreateSequence(measurement_id_seq)) # create the sequence
  op.create_table(
      'Measurement',
      sa.Column('DataSourceId',
                sa.Integer,
                sa.ForeignKey('DataSource.DataSourceId'),
                nullable=False),
      sa.Column('LocationId',
                sa.Integer,
                sa.ForeignKey('Location.LocationId'),
                nullable=False),
      sa.Column('MeasurementId',
                sa.Integer,
                measurement_id_seq, # the sequence as SchemaItem
                server_default=measurement_id_seq.next_value())) # next value of the sequence as default
      [...]
  op.create_primary_key('Measurement_pkey', 'Measurement',
                        ['DataSourceId', 'LocationId', 'Timestamp'])
  pass


def downgrade():
  op.execute(
      sa.schema.DropSequence(sa.Sequence('Measurement_MeasurementId_seq')))
  op.drop_constraint('Measurement_pkey', 'Measurement')
  op.drop_table('Measurement')
  pass
```